# SP19 - Site Collection Features - shows all features across all collections

Tags: feature-activation, farm-solution

We have a new Sp19 installation with 4 different web applications with 1 site collection each.

We deployed then some farm solutions to the specific sites.

When I open the list of Site Collection Features, there are also all other features, not deployed on the specific Site Collection.

Why are they showing there? I can activate all features (the .Webpart files get installed). Is there a way to hide them on Site Collection, where the solution is not installed?

Thanks and best regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

If you really have the the solutions only deployed to one `WebApplication`, the features will not show on any other `WebApplication`.

I suggest you verify that the solutions are not deployed globally.